# Connecting a primary key to row of another table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I created two tables:

- First table, "users", consisting of 'user_id' (primary key), 'user_name', 'user_email' and 'user_pw'
- Second table, "characters", consisting of of 'char_id' (primary key), 'uid', 'name', 'race' and age.

My intention is to let users create characters while the database assigns each created character to the correct user_id, so it's possible to find out who created what character.

(The login system is already working).

I started with the form, to fill in the character table:

```
<form method="post" action="includes/createcharacter.inc.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="race">
    <input type="number" name="age">
<button type="submit" name="create">Erstellen</button>
</form>
```

Followed by the createcharacter.inc.php file, which is doing the php behind it:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$race = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['race']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['age']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO characters (name, race, age) VALUES ('$name', '$race', '$age');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../createcharacter2.php?charactercreated");
exit();

}
```

It's no problem to insert the character data of a name, race and age now. But I can't figure out how to 'connect' the 'uid' row of my character-table with the user_id row of my user-table to assign every created character to a user_id.

I tried searching for an answer but I didn't know how to formulate it properly. I'm a beginner, so a detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: If the character is created by a user, who logged in, then you should already have the logged in user's id in your session. Insert it from there. Pls note that your script is exposed to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Start with any decent (and recent) book or tutorial on using php together with MySQL. I'm sure it would cover most of what you need to know. And before you go any further, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: See my profile for a PHP and PDO-based app system that illustrates how to use bound parameters (amongst other things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sweet jesus, sure took me smol brain all night to figure out how to insert it with the session. Here's my solution:

I simply added this input in my form:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {

    echo "
<form method='post' action='includes/createcharacter.inc.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='created_by' value='".$_SESSION['u_id']."'>
<input type='text' name='name'>
<input type='text' name='race'>
<input type='number' name='age'>
<button type='submit' name='create'>Erstellen</button>
</form>";

}
```

I also changed the name of the column 'uid' to 'created_by' like the - now deleted respond - suggested. Makes more sense to me. After that, the include-file looked like this:

```
    <?php

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$race = $_POST['race'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$created_by = $_POST['created_by'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO characters (name, race, age, created_by) VALUES ('$name', '$race', '$age', '$created_by');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../createcharacter2.php?charactercreated");
exit();

}
```

Thanks for the advice regarding the risk of sql injection attacks. I'm programming on XAMPP right now, but I'll make sure to learn more about prepared and bound queries.